# change event is not getting triggered in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angular js. I have a bootstrap  calendar in my application. On change of month, a change event needs to be triggered. But it is not getting triggered no matter where I place it.

Please find the snippet below.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('page loading completed');
    $('#datetimepicker').datepicker({
        inline : true,
        sideBySide : true,
        useCurrent : false,
        firstDay : 1
    }); 
    $(".ui-datepicker-month").on('change',function() {
        alert("change event triggered")
    });
});
```

Kindly help me.

Thanks,
Poorna

Comment: I recommend you looking into UI-Bootstrap, it's all the bootstrap directives done the Angular way, using jQuery is usually a no-go (unless it's in directives) Link: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: try this: `$(document).on('change', '.ui-datepicker-month', function() {
        alert("change event triggered")
    });`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But its not working

Comment: @PoornaMurali Can you provide your html code?

Comment: <div data-datetimepicker="" id="datetimepicker" class="col-md-12 col-lg-12"  style="position:absolute;">
       
       </div>

Answer (score 5):

Such things you should do in the DDO *(Directive Definition Object)*. Suppose this is your element datepicker:

```
<input type='text' data-datetimepicker="" id='datetimepicker'>  
<!---our directive------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------------->
```

Then you can create your directive like this:

```
myApp.directive('datetimepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', //<---A for attribute
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      el.find('input').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function() {
          console.log("change event triggered");
        });
    }
  };
});
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('dateApp', []);
myApp.directive('datetimepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', //<---A for attribute
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      el.find('input').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function() {
          $(this).after("change event triggered");
        });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='dateApp'>
  <div id='datetimepicker' data-datetimepicker="">
    <input type='text'>
    <!---our directive------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------------->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `change` event triggers when you leave the element like `blur` event. you could use `input` event too.

Comment: Hi Jai. The datetimepicker is a div element in my case and as you said I tried both input and change event. Its not triggered.Please find the snippet below.

Comment: dlcModule.directive('datetimepicker', function(){
     return {
        restrict:'A', //<---A for attribute
        link:function(scope, el, attrs){
            el.datepicker();
            el.on('input', function(){
                console.log("change event triggered");
            });
        }
     };
  });

Comment: @PoornaMurali Well i thought you have a jQuery datepicker but it was bootstrap's datetimepicker, so for that you can use `dp.change` custom event of datetimepicker. Have added a working code snippet. take a look at that how it is functioning.